# Drawing text to the screen using QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have been working on learning how to draw text to the screen with `QT` and I just can't figure out why it isn't drawing the text. 
This is the code that I use:

```
#include "dialog.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    QPainter painter(&w);
    painter.drawText(100,100,"hello");


    return a.exec();
}
```

It does work when I have it in the dialog class, when I override the `paintEvent` function, but should it not work if it is in the main function as well?

Comment: I guess the `delete s;` shouldn't actually be part of this snippet?

Comment: No I am trying to port my server from a console application to GUI and I forgot to delete that last part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well documented that you should only paint inside the `paintEvent`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QPainter.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#custom-widgets-and-painting

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent

http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_paint_outside_the_paintevent

You can get around the issue by using a `QPixmap` as a `QPaintDevice` and paint onto the `QPixmap` and then render it in the `paintEvent` function.  Also if you are attempting to use QPixmap outside of the main GUI thread, you will get runtime warnings and maybe some crashes.  To use images outside of the GUI thread, you need to use `QImage`, and then when you are back on your GUI thread, you can convert it to a `QPixmap`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also there are some other drawing elements, such as Qt Graphics View that may be closer to the drawing model you are looking to achieve.  Qt Graphics View is more complex than subclassing paintEvent, but it gives a lot more flexibility about persistence of objects and zoom and translation, and stuff like that.